# Form Post not working after showing details in webgrid in MVC 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, webgrid

I am using `Webgrid` in one of my project and all of the functionalities (Add, Edit, Delete, Details) are working fine. I am using ajax post method to delete the records on the same form.

So when I simply click on Delete it removes the record from the database. But when I first click on Category Name To show details of that category and after that I click on Delete it doesn't do anything.

The Click event of delete link is not working then. I don't know why is this happening.

Below is my view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Demo.Models.CategoryModel>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Category List";
}
@{
Demo.Models.CategoryModel category = new Demo.Models.CategoryModel();
}
@{

var gd = new WebGrid(Model, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 5, selectionFieldName: "selectedRow", ajaxUpdateContainerId: "gridContent");

}
<div class="main">
<h2>
    Category List</h2>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<div id="gridContent">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", null, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "updateForm" }))
    {
        @gd.GetHtml(tableStyle: "tbl",

                 headerStyle: "",

            alternatingRowStyle: "altRow",

            selectedRowStyle: "selectRow",

            mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,

            columns: gd.Columns(

            gd.Column("Category Name", format: (item) => item.GetSelectLink(item.Name)),

            gd.Column("Description", "Description"),

            gd.Column("ParentCategoryName", "Parent Category"),

            gd.Column("", header: "", format: @<text>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.CategoryId }, new { @class = "edit" })
        | <a href="JavaScript:void(0)" class="RemoveLink" data-id="@item.CategoryId" onclick = "return confirm('Do you want to Delete this Category?')">
            Delete</a>
        </text>, style: "last-item"
                     )
             ))

        <div class="cat-dets">
            @if (gd.HasSelection)
            {
                <h2>
                    Category Details</h2>
                category = (Demo.Models.CategoryModel)gd.Rows[gd.SelectedIndex].Value;
                <b>Category Id: </b> @category.CategoryId<br />  
                <b>Category Name: </b> @category.Name<br />            
                <b>Description</b> @category.Description<br />
                <b>Parent Category</b> @category.ParentCategoryName<br />
            }
        </div>
    }
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {        
    $(".RemoveLink").click(function () {            
        var recordToDelete = $(this).attr("data-id");            
        if (recordToDelete != '') {
            $.post("/Category/Delete", { "id": recordToDelete },
            function (data) {
                if (data.status == "success") {
                    window.location.href = window.location.href;
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Please help me if I have left something..

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

After some googling I found that this might be a issue between webgrid Get Method posting and my form's Post Method data posting. As the delete is also not functioning after paging and sorting. If anyone has used the **Form Post method with the webgrid** then please help me.

Comment: try moving this code `"return confirm('Do you want to Delete this Category?')"` inside the JS. You can decide in the function whether to delete the record or not based on user confirmation.

Comment: Check you browser console ..Is there any error?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have removed that code for testing. But still it is not working. I have checked that after selecting the CategoryName the href of a tag changed to `/category?selectedRow=4&__swhg=1380271113167`. Can this be a cause of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon, try defining the removelink click event with the jquery "on" binding:

```
$(".RemoveLink").on("click", function () { 
    ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried the above code. But still the problem is there.